Support in creating a slowly sliding menu?
As described in my title, I want to build a menu that slowly slides in from the right. I want to use details / summary  for the menu.
This is what it should look like:

My HTML markup of the navbar:
<nav id='sitenav' aria-labelledby='sitenav-label'>
  <h2 id='sitenav-label' class='visually-hidden'>Site-Navigation</h2>
  <details>
    <summary>Menü</summary>
    <ul>
      <li aria-current='page'>
        <details>
          <summary>Impressum &amp; rechtliches</summary>
          <ul>
            <li aria-current='sub-page' tabindex=0>
              <details>
                <summary>Impressum</summary>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href=''>Kontakt</a></li>
                  <li><a href=''>Fotodokumentationen</a></li>
                  <li><a href=''>Links</a></li>
                </ul>
              </details>
            </li>
            <li><a href=''>Nutzungsbedingungen</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>Datenschutz &amp; Urheberrecht</a></li>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </li>
      <li><a href=''>Website Erika Mustermann</a></li>
      <li><a href=''>Blog Max Mustermann</a></li>
      <li><a href=''>VLog Erika Mostermann</a></li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</nav>

The visible hamburger button (with the pseudo-elements ::after and ::before in <details>/<summery>) has position: sticky;
Now could someone please show me how I can slowly slide in my <ul> from the right. The submenu should then stop to the left of the button.
I'm interested in the principle of how to do it. Can someone please show me this using a simple example?

From a design point of view, don't do this.  It looks amateurish, and the delay is going to irritate power users.

Aha, interesting. Even if I use pseudo-elements to display a hamburger button behind "details" and then use the X to close it and hide the marker accordingly. Does that still apply then? So you would be more in favor of a normal hamburger button menu with "aria-expanded: true & false". Like this, for example, a rough outline (it's not complete!): https://codepen.io/Seb-B-/pen/dyEeYpE   == Also the JS is just a shell. Would you please help me to complete this? Would you please take the time to do this?

It's a very rare case when a UI animation does not annoy me.  It's an app, not a video game.  The animations are annoying and time-consuming.  And this is not a code-writing service.  StackOverflow is intended to solve specific problems.

Then please help me how to proceed and show me links.

First, get your site to work.  Fill in the content, make it functional.  Make sure the links work.  THEN, you can go tweak it for special effects.

OK, let's do it like this. You're not into playing around with CSS, but are more sober and matter-of-fact. Here's my new suggestion, what do you think? Please also make the browser window smaller.   http://misanthrop.bplaced.net/test/open-public/testseite-V2__10-06-24.html The only thing that is still wrong are the submenus, my ULs. Can you help me arrange these side menus that open to the left of the main menu? It is no longer important to me that something "slides in", the main thing is that the submenu is arranged to the left of the main menu. Or how would you handle the submenus?

You need to use CSS to do that kind of manipulation.  Look in particular at position: absolute, which positions the element relative to its parent.
